# Why is only one animation triggered when swapping elements?

Tags: angular

I'm trying to animate swapping of *ngFor elements on drag drop. Although the state of both elements gets changed in the drop handler (`letter.animation = 'none'` -> `'swapped'` only one animation is triggered.

I've tried removing the line where the swapping happens (`[this.letters[previousIndex], this.letters[currentIndex]] = [this.letters[currentIndex], this.letters[previousIndex]];`) and both of the elements get animated. Yet I cannot understand why only one triggers when I add the swapping back. Is it a timing issue?

StackBlitz sample code is here:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zqclw5

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your hunch about the timing issue worked... added setTimeout to get the effect you wanted:

updated function in **app.component.ts**:

```
  drop(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    const previousLetter: MyInterface = this.letters.filter((l) => l.id === e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain"))[0];
    const currentLetter: MyInterface = this.letters.filter((l) => l.id === e.target.id)[0];
    const previousIndex: number = this.letters.indexOf(previousLetter);
    const currentIndex: number = this.letters.indexOf(currentLetter);
    [this.letters[previousIndex], this.letters[currentIndex]] = [this.letters[currentIndex], this.letters[previousIndex]];
    previousLetter.animation = 'swapped'; 
    setTimeout(()=>{
      currentLetter.animation = 'swapped' ; 
    },5);
    console.log("After [p]:",previousLetter.name, " [c]:", currentLetter.name);
    }
```

demo [stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cycbvz?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks! It does change the color of the previous element now but it doesn't quite animate it (i.e the 1s duration and ease-in don't apply). Also with the added elements it sometimes works, sometimes not. But I feel like I'm getting closer to solving it, so thanks again!